# About Linux ( Im new to linux) To know how to do average to a execute file by using bash

Tags: linux, average

I will have to execute a file in Linux name as `pi` by entering the command  `./pi`

This command will instruct the program to calculate the `pi` value using 1 thread and output the time it takes in terms of seconds. I need to write a shell script called `avg.sh` to automate this operation: Run the `pi` `n` times and output the average time it takes to complete the calculation in your terminal. E.g.

```
./avg.sh 10
```

will execute `pi` `ten` times and output the average time it takes.

I didn't have any mindset in writing this shell script, any one can give me some suggestion about how to write it ?

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo `awk '{total+=$1} END {print total}' pi `
```

but after I execute `pi` `n` times it still come out with `0`.

Comment: set chmod using chmod +x

Comment: I know this command but now I need to write a shell script to output an average for the pi file, I don't have any mindset in writing the average shell script

Comment: so what is your code?

Comment: Is updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

The pi.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0
max=$1
while [ $j -lt $max ]
do
echo "scale=5; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
true $(( j = j+1 ))
done
```

The avg.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
start=`date +%s%N`
i=0
max=$1
while [ $i -lt $max ]
do
    time sh ./pi.sh 1
    true $(( i++ ))
done
end=`date +%s%N`
value=$((end-start))
echo "AVG is "$value "ms"
```

How to run code
./avg.sh 10 
this will give the result in milliseconds.

Comment: You can remove time function in "time sh ./pi.sh 1" for shorter output.